# Customize font or background image of a Flickr page

Tags: flickr, customization

Can I customize elements on a Flickr page, like the background image or the font color, the same way I can customize a YouTube channel or a Twitter page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

The only thing you can do is [customize the layout](http://www.flickr.com/account/prefs/layout/) of your public profile page.